# how to load data as string in mongodb using python?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, migration, mapping

```
import mysql.connector
import pymongo
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

mysql_host="**"
mysql_database="**"
mysql_schema = "**"
mysql_user="**"
mysql_password="**"

mongodb_host = "**"
mongodb_dbname = "**"

mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="**",
    database="**",
    user="**",
    password="***"
)
if (mysqldb.is_connected()):
    print("successfully Connected")

mycursor = mysqldb.cursor(dictionary=True) 

mycursor.execute("SELECT Name from MYSQLTABLE;")
Ndata = mycursor.fetchall()
print(Ndata)
mycursor.execute("SELECT location from MYSQLTABLE;")
Ldata = mycursor.fetchall()
print(Ldata)

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_host)
mydb = myclient[mongodb_dbname]
mycol = mydb["CASES"]

if len(Ndata) > 0:
   if len(Ldata) > 0:
        if len(iddata) > 0:
            x = mycol.insert_many([{  "Name" : Ndata, "location" : Ldata}]) 
            print(len(x.inserted_ids))
```

I have Written the above code, the data migrated through this process is an array,
**i want to migrate data as a string**
you can also suggest any other easy way to migrate data from mysql to mongodb using python through proper mapping (selected columns of mysql to selected fields of mongodb)